# Python & lxml / xpath: Parsing XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I need to get the value from the FLVPath from this link : http://www.testpage.com/v2/videoConfigXmlCode.php?pg=video_29746_no_0_extsite

```
from lxml import html

sub_r = requests.get("http://www.testpage.co/v2/videoConfigXmlCode.php?pg=video_%s_no_0_extsite" % list[6])
sub_root = lxml.html.fromstring(sub_r.content)

for sub_data in sub_root.xpath('//PLAYER_SETTINGS[@Name="FLVPath"]/@Value'):
     print sub_data.text
```

But no data returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `lxml.html` to parse the document, which causes lxml to lowercase all element and attribute names (since that doesn't matter in html), which means you'll have to use:

```
sub_root.xpath('//player_settings[@name="FLVPath"]/@value')
```

Or as you're parsing a xml file anyway, you could use `lxml.etree`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
print sub_data.attrib['Value']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "http://www.testpage.com/v2/videoConfigXmlCode.php?pg=video_29746_no_0_extsite"
response = requests.get(url)

# Use `lxml.etree` rathern than `lxml.html`, 
# and unicode `response.text` instead of `response.content`
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.text)

for path in doc.xpath('//PLAYER_SETTINGS[@Name="FLVPath"]/@Value'):
     print path
```